# Resize table with too many columns in iTextSharp PDF

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, itext

I try to generate an iTextSharp PDF file in ASP.NET C# and put a html table into the pdf file. 
The problem is that the method only works if the html table has a few columns. As soon as my table has more columns I do not get all the informations into the pdf file - they are simple cut away.

Is there a way to auto resize the table so that I get all the informations of a table into the pdf file? I'm already working in landscapge mode with the pdf page.

Here is the code where I generate the PDF file:

```
//Create a byte array that will eventually hold our final PDF
        Byte[] bytes;

        //Boilerplate iTextSharp setup here
        //Create a stream that we can write to, in this case a MemoryStream
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {

            //Create an iTextSharp Document which is an abstraction of a PDF but **NOT** a PDF
            using (Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f))
            {

                //Create a writer that's bound to our PDF abstraction and our stream
                using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms))
                {

                    //Open the document for writing
                    doc.Open();

                    StringBuilder sb = (StringBuilder)genObjects[1];
                    String tableName = sb.ToString();
                    Table myGenTable = (Table)genObjects[0];
                    String table = genObjects[2].ToString();

                    using (StringReader srHtml = new StringReader(table))
                    {

                        //Parse the HTML
                        iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, srHtml);
                    }

                    doc.Close();
                }
            }

            //After all of the PDF "stuff" above is done and closed but **before** we
            //close the MemoryStream, grab all of the active bytes from the stream
            bytes = ms.ToArray();
        }

        //Now we just need to do something with those bytes.
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + friendlyName+ ".pdf");
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
```

String table returns the correct html string (heading + html table).

If there isn't any solution is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: You should adjust column sizes in your table's html. You cannot do anything with a table after it is written to pdf, because it becomes just a bunch of texts and lines.

Comment: So can I resize the complete table html? the column size is already as small as possible..

Comment: Then use smaller font, or use larger "paper" size, or think of re-structuring your data. Pdf is nothing more than a virtual printer, so if you can't fit your html table into a printable page, it won't fit into pdf either.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it, for anyone who might still be struggling. Using the suggestions of others to edit the actual html, I added the CSS width property to table. This makes sure it'll fit. You will probably have to fiddle with adding font-size or other CSS properties to make it look good. Just add them after the width property.

```
    string addCssStyling(string srhtml, string fontsize)
    {
        var styled = $"<style>table{{width: 100%; font-size: {fontsize};}}</style>" + srhtml; 
        return styled;
    }
```